# Error "Expression does not produce a value" whenever I call my sub procedure

Tags: vb.net, winforms

At first, I will say I'm new here so I may not explain my problem properly. I use VB.Net Windows Forms applications. In this project I have to call a `sub` procedure from another class to display a report when the button is clicked. `sub` doesn't return a value I know that and I am used to that whenever I have a `sub` I will display the value inside the `sub` but I can't write the name of the text box in the other class . These are my codes I hope you can understand what I mean from it .

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim aobj As New Allowance
    Dim nam As String
    Dim ID, year, allowance, total As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        allowance = txtamount.Text
        total = aobj.calculatetotal(allowance)
        txtcalculate.ForeColor = Color.Red
        txtcalculate.Text = FormatNumber(total)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ID = txtid.Text
        year = txtyear.Text
        nam = txtname.Text
        txtreport.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        txtreport.Text = aobj.displayreport(nam, ID, year, total)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Allowance

    Function calculatetotal(ByVal a As Double) As Double
        Return (12 * 5 * a)
    End Function

    Sub displayreport(ByVal nam As String, ByVal id As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal tot As Double)

         (" The Student " & nam & " with ID: " & id & " will receivce a total allowance of " & tot & " for five years of study in YUC")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with C#?

Comment: `displayreport` is a sub and you assign `aobj.displayreport` to something which isn't possible. Also inside `displayreport` you just have an expression with nothing done to it (not even an assignment to some local) I think that cause problems too

Comment: Thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change displayreport to a function and return that string if you want to assign that string to txtreport.Text. Try changing it to:

```
Public Function displayreport(ByVal nam As String, ByVal id As Double, ByVal tot As Double) As String
    Return " The Student " & nam & " with ID: " & id & " will receivce a total allowance of " & tot & " for five years of study in YUC"
End Function
```

I also removed "y as double" because it isn't being used

Comment: The problem is my teacher want me to use a sub procedure not function    Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately the only ways to do that are way more over-complicated than what is necessary to achieve that task, but it can be done. You'll have to do some research about either invoking delegates, passing the textbox reference to your allowance class, or adding a public property to your allowance class that will hold the string created by your displayreport sub. Of course you've got to do what you've got to do for your class assignment, but if you ever approach a similar problem in the real world a sub is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you That really helped me .